# File::get() for Laravel returns null for existing file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

Using the **Laravel** framework, I am using the `File::get()` method to access the CSS file in the `public/css` directory returns null for a file that both exists, and has content:

the PHP code is:

```
private static $css_files = array(
                        "main"   => 'css/main.css',
                        "layout" => 'css/layout.css'
                        );

public static function get_css ($vars) {

    $file     = self::$css_files[$vars["file_name"]];
    $contents = File::get(path('public').$file, "File Not Found ($file)");

    return json_encode(array("file" => path('public').$file,
                         "contents" => $contents));

}
```

which returns to my webpage (from the js console in Chrome):

```
Object {file: "/var/www/sites/public/css/main.css", contents: null}
```

The file exists:

```
user@pc:~$ ls /var/www/sites/public/css/main.css
/var/www/sites/public/css/main.css
```

has content:

```
user@pc:~$ wc -l /var/www/sites/public/css/main.css
441 /var/www/sites/public/css/main.css
```

and the method doesn't trigger the `$default` argument in `File::get()` that it should if the file doesn't exist (tested with other valid and invalid names), so it has definitely found the file.

I've tried other files in the same PHP method (`get_css()`), from other target directories, and the same directory, and it returns the content of those files with no problem.

the permissions on the CSS file are ok:

```
user@pc:~$ ls -hal /var/www/sites/public/css/main.css 
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root 6.5K May 25 14:01 /var/www/sites/public/css/main.css
```

a separate PHP script, run from the command line returns the contents:

```
<?php    
  echo file_get_contents("/var/www/sites/public/css/main.css");
?>
```

here are the first few lines of the `main.css`

```
user@pc:~$ head /var/www/sites/public/css/main.css

/* Estilos principais*/

    body{
    background-color:#c5c5c5;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#999;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
```

Is this a bug?  Are there any reasons (that I can't see right now) for it not liking the contents of the CSS file?

Comment: `File::get()` is a very simple, 1 line function... `return (file_exists($path)) ? file_get_contents($path) : value($default);` can you confirm that a) `file_exists()` works in isolation, and b) `json_encode()` works with other contents?

Comment: that's what I don't understand... `json_encode()` works with other content (even the contents from another css file from the same directory) and `file_exists()` work correctly as well.  The function is returning what it thinks is the contents of the file.. I am passing a second argument to the `get()` method, so it shouldn't just return null.  I now think the issue is with `file_get_contents()`, but no idea why!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it, two of the files were not utf-8, and `json_encode()` was choking on the non-utf-8 content, and return `null`, the issue was not in `File::get()`, but in `json_encode()`.

Case closed!